# ListBox update Items from remote

Tags: uwp

I have troubles understanding how to handle `ListBox`es in C# UWP. It fails on me when I try to get the Items from somewhere on the internet. I tried reading up on `ObservableCollection`s and to be honest did not understand it fully and my tests still failed.

Why can't the `ListBox` update and show the content - it is there when I run a debugger.

Comment: can you show what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little sample app showing all the options you have around the databinding. You can download it here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApdKhb5zPLrRypBoZbHqguGIMqCz2A

The highlights:

part 1 loading data

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // Fake waiting on result from a webservice / website;

    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
        new Item { Title = "Item 1" },
        new Item { Title = "Item 2" },
    };
    Bindings.Update();


    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    Items[1].Title = "Updated item via PropertyChanged";
}
```

In the onnavigatedto i fake that i am loading data from a webservice (by using the delay of 2 seconds). Then after the delay i am assigning my Items property with a observablecollection. Now this Items property need the interface INotifyPropertyChanged implentation or you need to call Bindings.Update(). for this i picked the last one. I also created a Item class which is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. To demonstrate this i change the property Title of the second item in the last 3 seconds later. In the UI you will see this autoamtically get updated